# XSS and Content Security Policy

Tags: xss, javascript, content-security-policy

Can XSS be prevented **100%** by setting the content security policy as `default-src 'self'`? Is there any way XSS can happen in that case? One possibility I can think of is injecting user input into one of your scripts dynamically at the server-side, do you agree? Are there any other vulnerabilities you can think of?

Comment: if you inject something "server-side", it's not `XSS`, it's just `S`...

Comment: @dandavis I think he is referring to stored XSS.

Answer (score 3):

CSP in such a configuration *should* enable the following security measures:

- Disable inline scripts
- Disable inline styles
- Disable all use of dangerous JavaScript functions (e.g. eval)
- Force all content to be loaded only from the existing domain. This applies to:

  - JavaScript
  - CSS
  - Fonts (e.g. WOFF)
  - Ajax (XmlHttpRequest and similar)
  - WebSockets
  - Video
  - Objects (e.g. Flash, Java applets)
  - SVGs
  - WebGL assets
  - Frames
  - Images
  - Probably some other things I forgot...

As such, XSS should be possible only in cases where resources on the domain can be controlled by an attacker, as you mentioned.

You can lock CSP down further by setting `default-src 'none'`, then explicitly enabling only content types which you are expecting to use on the site. This helps lower your attack surface further by disabling content types like Flash, Java applets, SVGs, canvas, etc. when you're not using them.

One additional vector you may not have considered is [Path-Relative Stylesheet Overrides (PRSSI)](http://blog.portswigger.net/2015/02/prssi.html), otherwise known as Relative Path Overwrite (RPO) vulnerabilities. These work by exploiting URL handling behaviour in some CMS software, whereby path characters appear after a script are taken as parameters (e.g. `example.com/wiki/index.php/Something` shows the `Something` page). When a path-relative stylesheet is included (e.g. `main.css` rather than `/main.css`) this can be sometimes abused. In our example, because `main.css` is imported relative to the current path, an inclusion in the example URL above would cause the browser to try to load `example.com/wiki/index.php/main.css` as a stylesheet. If you can create a wiki page called `main.css`, this would allow you to control the content of that stylesheet, and potentially load malicious CSS (e.g. with the `expression` directive). You can do the same thing with path relative JavaScript imports. The fix here is to always reference content by its full canonical path.

Comment: there's no need to worry about "malicious CSS" executing code anymore, and JS is imported relative to the document, not the importing file.

Comment: "there's no need to worry about malicious CSS executing code anymore" - got a citation on that?

Comment: And as for "and JS is imported relative to the document, not the importing file", that's the problem. The browser *thinks* the document is in a deeper path than it really is.

Comment: AFAIK all css execution vectors are at least 5 years outmoded: [dec 2011 for expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx), [IE9 for behaviors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532147(v=vs.85).aspx), [firefox4 for -moz-binding](http://blog.innerht.ml/cascading-style-scripting/) ... did I miss anything? looking at the % usage of vulnerable browsers suggest it's not worth worrying about anymore; time would be better spent crafting CSPs

Comment: i should point out that it might be possible to use CSS alone to fool users into doing something dumb, like baiting them to type in a non-clickable url by showing an "error message", but that's not XSS...

Comment: @dandavis it's true CSS expressions have gone away, but there is a class of "scriptless" attacks using CSS to exfiltrate data. e.g. https://www.nds.rub.de/media/emma/veroeffentlichungen/2012/08/16/scriptlessAttacks-ccs2012.pdf

Comment: @oreoshake: their demo at https://html5sec.org/webkit/test doesn't work as described (i ping Z). since the attack is four years old, it's probably busted, and since it's blocked by csp anyway, not a big concern. these kind of things make for good papers but poor real-world attacks (like clearjacking). when these are discovered to be viable (ex `:visited` computed styles) they are patched soon. there are better things to worry about ;)

Answer (score 0):

`default-src 'self'` allows XSS via JSONP and content-type sniffing attacks:

> Of particular note is our lack of self in our source list. While
>   sourcing JavaScript from self seems relatively safe (and extremely
>   common), it should be avoided when possible.
>
> There are edge cases that any developer must concern themselves with
>   when allowing self as a source for scripts. There may be a forgotten
>   JSONP endpoint that doesn’t sanitize the callback function name. Or,
>   another endpoint that serves user-influenced content with a
>   content-type that could be sniffed by browsers as JavaScript. GitHub
>   has several such endpoints. For example, we return commit diffs as
>   text/plain.

http://githubengineering.com/githubs-csp-journey/

Comment: CORS has eliminated the need for JSONP, and ALL user input needs sanitized...